# get list of files in order of creation

Tags: c#

i am currently reading in a list of files from different directories into a LIST:

```
public List<string> MapMyFiles()
        {
            List<string> batchaddresses = new List<string>();
            foreach (object o in lstViewAddresses.Items)
            {
                try
                {
                    batchaddresses.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(o.ToString(), "*-E.esy"));
                }
                catch
                {
                    if (MessageBox.Show(o.ToString() + " does not exist. Process anyway?", "Continue?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
                        == DialogResult.Yes) { }
                    else
                    {
                        Application.Exit();
                    }
                }

            }
```

how would i sort them by date of creation in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `FileInfo` object and sort by the `CreationTime` property before you return it as the `FullName` which is the path

```
public List<string> MapMyFiles()
{
    List<FileInfo> batchaddresses = new List<FileInfo>();
    foreach (object o in lstViewAddresses.Items)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(o.ToString(), "*-E.esy");
            files.ToList().ForEach(f => batchaddresses.Add(new FileInfo(f)));
        }
        catch { }
    }

    return batchaddresses.OrderBy(f => f.CreationTime).Select(f => f.FullName).ToList();
}
```

Comment: +1 but you could remove the `.ForEach` by switching `Directory.GetFiles()` to `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()`. You will end up with a prepopulated `FileInfo[]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<string> pathsToSearch = ...
List<string> batchaddresses = pathsToSearch
    .SelectMany(p => new DirectoryInfo(p).GetFiles("*-E.esy"))
    .OrderBy(f => f.CreationTime)
    .Select(f => f.Name)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is a working sample.

BTW, I tried to improve the performance by replacing the `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` with `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles`. But the procedure timing seems to be quite the same (only the few ms difference). Can anybody explain this?

```
    GetOrderedFileList2(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Program Files\"));

    public List<string> GetOrderedFileList2(DirectoryInfo dirInfo)
    {
        using (new StopWatchPrinter())
        {
            List<string> orderedFileList = dirInfo.EnumerateFiles("*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                .OrderBy(f => f.CreationTime)
                .Select(f => f.Name)
                .ToList();

            Debug.Print(string.Format("\n\n *** EnumerateFiles() - found: {0} files ***", orderedFileList.Count));

            return orderedFileList;
        }
    }
```